# Rails autoloads lib classes and modules in staging but not when pushed to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

I recently upgraded my rails app from Thin to Puma, hosted on Heroku. Everything works perfectly on staging environment, but when I deploy to production no modules or classes seem to be loaded.

The app launches and run on production but whenever one of the classes in my `/lib` directory is needed I get a `NameError` (uninitialized constant) error.

In my `application.rb` file this is where I load the lib files:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib", "#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Running Rails 3.1.1 and Ruby 2.1.1

I can't work out why they would load in staging but not production. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try `Rails.root` instead of `config.root`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try add those line to application.rb:

```
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

It worked for me